# Entity Framework Core, How to update if already exists, else insert

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm pulling data from an external API and storing this in my SQL Server database using Entity Framework Core. I pull data from this API every day so I want to check for rows that already exist by `Id`, in case the `Id` already exists in the database, then the row should be updated. Otherwise a new record should be added.

The data from the API is deserialized from JSON and stored in the data variable as a `List<Customers>.` Currently I came up with the following code but it still keeps making new records even if the row already exists.

```
string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Customers>>(apiResponse);

foreach (Customers customer in data)
{
    if (db.Customers.Any(x => x.Id == customer.Id))
    {
        db.Customers.Update(customer);
    }
    else
    {
        db.Customers.Add(customer);
    }

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Model**

```
public class Customers
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string BranchId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string CustomerNameTopdesk { get; set; }

    public string CustomerNamePRTG { get; set; }
}
```

**DbContext**

```
public DbSet<Customers> Customers { get; set; }
```

**EDIT**

After running the debugger it throws the following exception, the Customer values seem to be empty but my data variable is properly filled with values.

> 'customer' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'

Comment: It should work, please check records in database and the value of data variable.

Comment: Start transaction before loop. Also consider to use `Contains` instead of iteration.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can use Contains in this case. I'd have to loop over every value and can't just search for one right?

Comment: I've edited my question, after debugging it seems to throw an NullReferenceException.

Comment: Only you can see where this NRE comes from.